# Closing a window without triggering Window_Closed event

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

This is a WPF/C# application and I'm having more of a design problem than a code problem.

I have 5 separate *.xaml files implementing a class derived from window. So, 5 windows. This is a wizard-type of application so each window has back/next buttons that will create a new window, hide itself, and show the new window.

This isn't purely navigation based (so I'm not using pages) because sometimes I want to skip a window, or go back to the first window, etc.

Every time a new window is opened the parent window sets itself as the owner of the new window and hides itself. When the back button is used the new window shows the owner and closes itself. This works fine for navigation.

I'm having a problem when someone actually closes the window as opposed to using the navigation. If they close the window, Alt-F4, hit the X, etc it should close the whole app.

My 'go back' button also closes the window, which triggers Window_Closed, closing the whole app.

I'm trying to think of a way to close the whole app when the user closes the window, but close only the window (not hide it, actually dispose of it) and show the owner when they click back. I can't seem to do the latter without triggering the former.

Any suggestions? I'm just not thinking about this the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of flipping between Windows, I would recommend flipping between UserControls in panels.  You have the full functionality of a Window except you don't have to worry about its open/closed state.  Just have the UserControls toggle visibility based on the Next/Previous commands.

You might consider looking into doing navigation for your wizard.  You can do this in WPF as [demonstrated here](http://windowsclient.net/learn/video.aspx?v=4190).

With navigation, you have a single window that hosts pages.  You can then issue a command to navigate to a particular page and it will automatically flip to the page without you having to worry about control visibility.

Comment: I looked into using navigation and actually watched that specific video. That really isn't what I want though. That has more of a web page navigation and lets you jump between pages. I have very specific rules of what 'back' and 'next' should do in each case - they may skip pages or run code depending on the context.

I'm also using usercontrols in each of my 5 windows, they're essentially 1 or more user controls now, so that might be worth looking into. I'd have to relocate the logic for back/next out of the control and into the window but that might be worth it

Comment: @user783106 - Yes, you will want to pop the back/next into the main window and out of your hosted controls.  When they click Back/Next, you can then use any rules you want to pick the next UserControl.  Just toggle the visibility yourself if you don't want to use Navigation.

Comment: But just a side note, you can use rules with your navigation.  There is a method called NavigateTo( "string name of page" ).  When they click a button, in the code-behind you would run any logic you need to determine the next page.  When you are ready to display it, just call NavigateTo() passing in the name of the next page (which can be totally dynamic if need be).

Comment: Thanks, that is a useful tip but as my first WPF application (and first C#) application I have enough problems at the moment so even though the idea of multiple windows isn't great, it is easiest to get up and running with the time I have compared to the navigation pages. I do like the idea of one window with multiple user controls though, I think that is the way I'm going to go. It is a bit of a redesign and a little more complexity but fixes enough problems to make it worthwhile

Comment: Following up I decided to go with the single WPF window and clear/load user controls as well as show/hide/enable/disable any of my own navigation buttons as needed. It turned out to be much better than having the multiple windows. Thanks for suggesting this.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would not make 5 different *windows*, but a single window, and replace the content of it when the wizard page changes. This would look more natural for the user, and the problem won't manifest itself at all.

Second, if you insist on the design with multiple windows, I would just unsubscribe from Close in button Click handler (and resubscribe when I reopen the window).

Comment: From the user's point of view they don't know there are 5 different windows. The positions and sizes are the same. I do see your point though.

Do you have an example of unsubscribing specifically from the click handler on the close button? There are other ways to close the window too, such as alt-f4. Is the suggestion to disassociate the Closed event of the window with any handler in the case when I'm closing it in my back button? That would make sense I think